# Setting the major mode of a new buffer interactively

Tags: major-mode, ido

When creating a new buffer via:

1. `C-x b`
2. `NonExistentBufferName` `RET` `RET`

I would like Emacs to prompt me for the major mode this buffer is going to use upon opening.
Moreover, I want Emacs to infer the major mode in some cases based on the buffer's name:

1. `C-x b`
2. `test.org`(no such buffer/file so far) `RET` `RET`
   => org-mode is used without asking me anything.

Could anybody advice on how I can achieve this? Package or, probably, just pure elisp with its hooks and advice?

P.S.
I'm using `ido` if it matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is not exactly what you're asking, but the Emacs way to solve this problem is to use `C-x C-f` instead of `C-x b` (if you don't want to create a file, just don't use `C-x C-s` in that buffer).

Comment: Thanks, @Stefan, for such a prompt response. Yeah, that seems to be a solution. I was a bit worried about the scenario when I finally decide to save that buffer. If it is already associated with a path and I want to change the final location, it is a problem. But seems like `C-x C-w` solves this problem.